# Joining models in eloquent Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, eloquent

I am new to Laravel. 
Here is my schema:

```
Schema::create('cluster_info', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('code')->unique();
            $table->string('pa_lastname');
            $table->string('pa_firstname');
            $table->string('pa_middlename');
            $table->string('pa_suffix');
            $table->integer('branch_id');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
 Schema::create('cluster_grouping', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('cluster_id');
            $table->integer('client_id');
            $table->timestamps();

        }); 
 Schema::create('branch', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('code')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('region');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
```

I want to join `cluster_info` to the `branch`. So in my `Cluster_Info` Model:

```
 public function Branches(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Branch');
    }
```

and when I call it in my control it has `null` values

```
$cluster = new App\Cluster_Info;
dd($cluster->Branches());
```

Comment: what is your foreign key in for `cluster_info` in `branch` ?

Comment: Define foreign key in branch table of cluster_info table.

Comment: @BalrajAllam how can i define the foreign key of branch table in clusteri_info?

Comment: Rollback your migration using `php artisan migrate:rollback` and then add `$table->integer('cluster_info_id')` `$table->foreign('cluster_info_id')->references('id')->on('cluster_info')` in branch schema.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) that what is foreign key and how you can write foreign key in your table. See the naming convention discussion for laravel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927700/laravel-database-table-and-column-naming-conventions)

If you added table name and foreign key properly than you relationship should work. else you can use below method and pass your foreign key as second parameter. Read Deatils for [One to One Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Branch', 'foreign_key');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your local and foreign key:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Branch', 'id', 'cluster_id');
```

It might be in the way you wrote in your controller, because in order to a relationship to exist, the relationship method should be requested on a existing `Cluster_Info` instance, like this:

```
$clusters = Cluster_Info::all();
foreach($clusters as $clusterInfo) {
  dump($clusterInfo->Branches());
}
```

Or using [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$clusters = Cluster_Info::with('Branches')->get();
```

Also make sure Eloquent knows about your table name, as I'm not sure you meet Laravel's conventions here.

```
class Cluster_Info {
  protected $table = 'cluster_info';
}
```

For readability, I would advise using a method like `branch()` instead of `Branches()`, for it should only return just one result. Also take a look at [Eloquent model conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), they can make your life so much easier.

Comment: ive tried eager loading and this is the result

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'branch.cluster__information_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `branch` where `branch`.`cluster__information_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 64, 67))