# No data fetched from associated table : Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have `users` and `user_roles` tables, and id of user_roles is used as `foreign key` in `users`. I fetched data from `users` using `User::with('userRole')->find($user)`. In returned result `userRole` is present, however it is empty, instead it was supposed to have data from `user_roles` for the particular `foreign key`.

Please, share what can be the possible issues with the functionality or if anyone can explain working of laravel associations in brief.

```
/* User Model */
public function userRole()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UserRole');
}

/* UserRole Model */
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Thank You,

Comment: Handling User/Group (roles) is usually  a Many-to-many relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many. You'd use 3 tables: `users`, `roles`, and `roles_users` (or `users_roles`, naming conventions aside), but only 2 models: `User` and `Role`.

Comment: Is it not be achieved using two tables? As, in my case a user will have only one role.

Comment: For sure, my comment was more information on the usual approach to this. In the `users` table, you would need a `user_role_id` (or equivalent) that matches a row on `uses_roles` table. You relationships might not work for a couple of reasons; it's defined backwards, the keys are not what Laravel is expecting, etc etc. The documentation is pretty good for all of this, so have a read. Also, are you getting a specific error?

Comment: @TimLewis Yes, I have `user_role_id` in `users` table. No, I am not getting any specific error.

Comment: Just not getting any data back eh? Usually it would give you a SQL error for invalid column. `User::with('userRole')->find($user)` Is `$user` an ID in this case? (Would be redundant otherwise)

Comment: `$user` is the parameter passed into the `show` method of `UserController`. After performing `print_r` on it, `json` object printed.

Comment: That might be an issue then; I believe `->find()` works with an ID. If you call `$userFromDB = User::with('userRole')->find($user);` following by a `dd($userFromDB)` (fancier output method available to Laravel) is it `null`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165069/discussion-between-bluesuiter-and-tim-lewis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tim and @Nikola
Thank you, for your efforts mates.

However, I found the reason behind the problem. It was because the wrong naming of `userRole` function in `User` model.

I was using `foreign key` of `user_roles` as `user_roles_id` in `users` table and defined function with name of `userRole` in `User` model. This leads to ORM not found the relevant column for attaching `user_roles` data.

The solution is either I have to change the name of `user_roles_id` to `user_role_id` or `userRole` function name to `userRoles`. And I choose the first one and it worked fine. :)

For reference on the naming conventions of laravel please refer to [Laravel - Database, Table and Column Naming Conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927700/laravel-database-table-and-column-naming-conventions).

Answer (score 3):

Many to many relationships in Laravel often require you to have `2 models` and `3 tables`. One to many relationships require you to have `2 models` and `2 tables`. One to one relationship also requires you to have `2 models` and `2 tables`.

**Many to many relationship**

Let's take `User` and `Role` models, since each `User` can have multiple roles and one `Role` can be assigned to different users, you will naturally want a `Many to many` relationship. Now, you will need to create an intermediate table in which you will store the results, why? Because you already defined both `User` and `Role` and since it is `Many to many` none of those objects will have any identifier of the other one inside of them, but rather will have their own identifier in the intermediate table, and this is how `Laravel` fetches the relationship, it connects `Models` primary key with `foreign key` inside of the `intermediate table`.

**One to many relationships**

Let's take `User` and `Role` models again and let's say that this time, one `Role` can be assigned to multiple users, but one `User` can ONLY have 1 `Role`. Naturally you will have a field `role_id` inside of your `User` model and you will connect `role_id` from users with `id` from roles.

**One to one relationships**

Lets take `User` and `Role` models again :D Let's say you want to create a separate `Role` for every user, then you will have `2 models` and `2 tables` where your users table will have all the users and your roles table will contain `id, name, user_id` and now when you try to retrieve the relationship, if you define `one to one` laravel will return only 1 result, no matter if you have multiple same `user_id` on the `roles table`, `Laravel` will return only 1 role because you told him explicitly it's `1-to-1` relationship.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of `one to one` relationship:

```
/* User Model */
public function userRole()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UserRole', 'user_role_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Nikola for explaining relationships context. However, if you can also add examples for defining relations in models, it will be easy to understand the usage.

Comment: I am using `One-To-Many` relationship in my implementation. I have an question to ask: Is this is the right way to use `One-To-Many` relationship? As, it is mentioned in question.